# how can make this xaml design?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
+------------------------------------+
|____________________________________|
|          |              |          |
|          |              |          |
.          .              .          .
.          .              .          .
.          .              .          .
.          .              .          .
.          .              .          .
```

---

below code didnt run. how can i learn ui design in xaml on xamarin.forms ......................................................................

```
     <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0" x:Name="GrdContainer">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="9*" />      
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource DashboardMenusHeadGridStyle}">
        <Label Text="başlık ... " TextColor="Black"></Label>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Column="0" Row="1" Style="{StaticResource DashboardMenusMyProfileGridStyle}">
       <Label Text="0,0" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
    </Grid> 
    <Grid Column="1" Row="1" Style="{StaticResource DashboardMenusWillGoEventsGridStyle}">
        <Label Text="1,0" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>     
    </Grid>
    <Grid Column="2" Row="1" Style="{StaticResource DashboardMenusAllEventGridStyle}">
        <Label Text="2,0" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>    
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0" x:Name="GrdContainer">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="9*" />      
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Text="başlık ... " TextColor="Black"></Label>
  <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="0,0" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
  <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="1,0" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>     
  <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="2,0" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>    
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly start learning and implementing all the layouts and then start using controls, it will help you in designing a good UI. Stack Layout and Grid should be your first priority https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/ this link contains everything.